# a href nested in DIV element in ASP.NET C#

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, href

My question is quite simple,
I created a DIV, with a HyperLink control in it.
As following:

```
<div id="divOne" style="width: 500px;">  
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="hlOne" Text="hlOne"
     NavigateUrl="http://www.StackOverflow.com" />  
</div>
```

I created an `onclick` event in jQuery for the DIV as well:

```
$('#divOne').click(function() {  
    alert('You clicked on the DIV element');  
});
```

My goal is to trigger this event when the DIV area is clicked (working fine), BUT-
When the HyperLink is clicked, I need the page to redirect WITHOUT triggering the DIV 'onclick' event (can use JavaScript or jQuery as needed).

Thanks all!

Comment: @Gal - Use the `1010` button on the edit toolbar for formatting, just highlight the code chunk and it'll tab it all over 4 spaces to get nice color coding :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, stop the `click` event from bubbling up using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), like this:

```
$('#divOne a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

`return false;` would also stop the bubbling...but it would also stop the link from being followed, that's why we have `.stopPropagation()` :)